# AEM 6.2 - Set value in one dropdown based on selection of another dropdown value

Tags: aem

In AEM 6.2, I have the first drop-down which has three values [x, y, z] and the second drop-down with these values [abc, def, ghk]. My requirement is that when I select the value [y] in the first drop-down, I want to disable the second drop-down and set the value as [def]. The author should not be able to change the value of the second drop-down when [y] is selected in the first down (it should be defaulted to [def]).

Comment: Can anybody share any pointers, please?

Comment: Is this for touch or classic? You’re going to have to write custom JS to enable this, and there are a few resources online that can help you.

Comment: this is for touch ui. Can you point to any direct resource which can help in achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** This solution is not meant to be perfect, I tested it and it works on a vanilla installation of AEM 6.2 (no CFP or SP installed). The javascript API's may change with CFP's and SP's. However, the solution below should serve as a good foundation and with a bit of debugging you can make it work with your environment.

It seems like there was no good resources on the web, at-least not ones that do what you're asking properly, so I wrote a solution:

I created the following component:

**HTML:**

```
<h1> dropdown test placeholder</h1>
<h4>first: ${properties.first}</h4>
<h4>second: ${properties.second}</h4>
```

**cq:dialog**

> Please note the following:
>
> 1. The root node of the dialog has `extraClientlibs="[dropdown-author-clientlib]"` this is our clientlib category where we will add the custom code
> 2. The dropdown nodes have id's `id="first-dropdown"` and `id="first-dropdown"` so we can easily select them in our code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
    xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" 
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
    jcr:title="Example Dialog"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
    extraClientlibs="[dropdown-author-clientlib]">
    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns" />
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <first jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" fieldLabel="First" id="first-dropdown" name="./first" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <default jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="(default)" value="" />
                            <x jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="x" value="x" />
                            <y jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="y" value="y" />
                            <z jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="z" value="z" />
                        </items>
                    </first>
                    <second jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" fieldLabel="second" id="second-dropdown" name="./second" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <def jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="def" value="def" />
                            <ghi jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="ghi" value="ghi" />
                            <abc jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="abc" value="abc" />
                            <default jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="(default)" value="" />
                        </items>
                    </second>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

**The clientlib:**
Under the component, I created this clientlib:

categories="[dropdown-author-clientlib]"

> I wont get into creating a clientlib, it's simple enough.

in the clientlib, I added the following `script.js` file:

```
(function(){
  var $doc = $(document);
  var $first, $second;
  $doc.on('foundation-contentloaded', function(e) { // 'foundation-contentloaded' triggered when dialog is ready
    $dialog = $(e.target); 
    // get "Coral UI 2" select instance reference: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/components/Coral.Select.html#
    firstSelect = $dialog.find('#first-dropdown').data('select'); // coral ui select instance
    secondSelect = $dialog.find('#second-dropdown').data('select'); // coral ui select instance

    // enables/disables the second select based on value provided
    function toggleSecond(firstVal){
      if(firstVal === 'y'){
        secondSelect._select('def', 'def'); // first is the value, second is the display text
        secondSelect.set('disabled', true)
        // we need to remove 'disabled' attr from the actul select inorder for it to be submitted with form submit
        secondSelect.$element.find('select').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      else {
        secondSelect.set('disabled', false)
      }
    }

    // run when dialog opens
    toggleSecond(firstSelect.getValue());

    // 'selected' is not in the documentation, change does not work, found this by looking into the js code
    firstSelect.on('selected', function(e){
      toggleSecond(e.selected);
    })
  });
})();
```

Now when you select `y` in the first dropdown, the second one will be set to 'def' and disabled.

> The code above should be simple enough to follow, I added comments to make it even easier to follow. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: this is not working for me. I am getting "undefined" when i put the alert in clientlib.  alert ('firstSelect.....'+firstSelect) - firstSelect.....undefined 
  2) alert ('secondSelect......'+secondSelect) --secondSelect......undefined and dialog gives this alert  alert('dialog.....'+$dialog)----dialog.....[object Object]

Comment: So I made this into a component for geometrixx outdoors. If you have the sample geometrics outdoors project, you can install [this package](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uKfuY_D5b3t-wxwVk02sArHN5mdSKsxI/view?usp=sharing) and test it in one of the geometrixx outdoors pages

Comment: It works but the width of the fields in AEM dialog has been reduced. I mean earlier the size was big, but now the field size has been reduced. Dialog is still big but the fields are appearing of reduced size. When i remove the scrip.js, dialog field appears fine.

Comment: Seems like it’s something to do with your environment, on my environment it works fine and width is not reduced

Comment: I just noticed that it was working for me earlier because I had set the category name as 'cq.authoring.dialog'. But when I changed the category name to match yours 'dropdown-author-client lib', then when I select the first drop-down value, then correct value gets set in the second dropdown. But the second dropdown is not getting disabled. That's the only issue left like the second dropdown is not getting disabled. Any pointers, please?

Comment: I tested this on a vanilla AEM 6.2 installation and it works just fine. It seems like the environment you are testing on is not the same as mine. And I have no control over your environment so it would be hard to troubleshoot. I'd suggest you spend some time debugging. This answer is not meant to be a one solution for all, but the basic concepts should get you to a solution that works with your environment.